# font size change with jquery

Tags: jquery, font-size

I have a page where I need to change the font size.

A simplified setup is this one:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">Some dummy text in here</div>
<a href="#" class=".decreaseFont">decrease</a>

<a href="#" class=".increaseFont">increase</a>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".increaseFont").click(function () {
        $(".box").css("font-size", "12px");
    });

    $(".decreaseFont").click(function () {
        $(".box").css("font-size", "11px");
    });

});
```

**CSS:**

```
.box {
    font-size:11px;
    padding:30px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

For some reason I could not identify this is not working. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D4fT6/) also.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you classname

```
class=".increaseFont"
```

Either remove the `.` from it

```
<a href="#" class="decreaseFont">decrease</a>
<a href="#" class="increaseFont">increase</a>
```

Can be selected using

```
$(".decreaseFont")
$(".increaseFont")
```

**Or escape it in your selector**

```
<a href="#" class=".decreaseFont">decrease</a>
<a href="#" class=".increaseFont">increase</a>
```

Can be selected using

```
 $(".\\.decreaseFont")
 $(".\\.increaseFont")
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/D4fT6/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

It's because you apply class names wrong:

```
<a href="#" class=".decreaseFont">decrease</a>

<a href="#" class=".increaseFont">increase</a>
```

just remove dots as it is in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D4fT6/3/)

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be dot `.` in your class name. It should be

```
<a href="#" class="decreaseFont">decrease</a>
<a href="#" class="increaseFont">increase</a>
```